# Forbidden error to connect to kubernetes cluster in gitlab CI

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to get access to my kubernetes cluster in my self hosted gitlab instance as it is described in the [docs](https://gitlab.jaqua.de/help/user/project/clusters/deploy_to_cluster.md#deployment-variables).

```
deploy:
  stage: deployment
  script: 
    - kubectl create secret docker-registry gitlab-registry --docker-server="$CI_REGISTRY" --docker-username="$CI_DEPLOY_USER" --docker-password="$CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD" --docker-email="$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL" -o yaml --dry-run=client | kubectl apply -f -
```

But I do get the error

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=secrets", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=Secret"
Name: "gitlab-registry", Namespace: "gitlab"
from server for: "STDIN": secrets "gitlab-registry" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab:default" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "gitlab"
```

I do not understand the error. Why do I get a forbidden error?

---

*Update*

The kubernetes cluster is integrated in gitlab at instance level.

But running `kubectl config view` in the CI pipeline gives me

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
```

---

*Update2*

Thanks to AndD, the secret can be created with this role / service account:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  namespace: gitlab
  name: gitlab-deploy
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: use-secrets
  namespace: gitlab
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: gitlab
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: gitlab-deploy
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

But running a simple apply for this namespace.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: myns
```

gives me a similar error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=namespaces", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=Namespace"
Name: "myns", Namespace: ""
from server for: "namespace.yaml": namespaces "myns" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab:default" cannot get resource "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "myns"
```

I used ClusterBinding to get this working even for a different namespace. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kubernetes makes use of a Role-based access control (RBAC) to prevent Pods and Users from being able to interact with resources in the cluster, unless they are not authorized.

From the error, you can see that Gitlab is trying to use the `secrets` resource and also that it is using as `ServiceAccount` the `default` service account in its namespace.

This means that Gitlab is not configured to use a particular ServiceAccount, which means it makes use of the default one (there's a default service account in each namespace of the cluster)

---

You can attach role auth and permissions to service accounts by using `Role` / `ClusterRole` and `RoleBinding` / `ClusterRoleBinding`.

Roles or ClusterRoles describe permissions. For example, a Role could be:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: gitlab
  name: secret-user
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

and this states that "whoever has this role, can do whatever (all the verbs) with secrets **but only** in the namespace `gitlab`"

If you want to give generic permissions in all namespaces, you can use a ClusterRole instead, which is very similar.

Once the Role is created, you then can attach it to a User, a Group or a ServiceAccount, for example:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: use-secrets
  namespace: gitlab
subjects:
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: gitlab
roleRef:
  # "roleRef" specifies the binding to a Role / ClusterRole
  kind: Role # this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: secret-user # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

and this bind the role previously created to the `ServiceAccount` called default in the namespace `gitlab`.

Then, **all** Pods running in the namespace `gitlab` and using the `default` service account, will be able to use `secrets` (use the verbs listed in the Role) **but only** in the namespace specified by the Role.

---

As you can see, this aspect of Kubernetes is pretty complex and powerful, so have a look at the docs because they explain things **really** well and are also full of examples:

Service Accounts - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/

RBAC - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

A list of RBAC resources - [How to refer to all subresources in a Role definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872201/how-to-refer-to-all-subresources-in-a-role-definition)

---

**UPDATE**

You are doing nothing wrong. It's just that you are trying to use the resource `namespace` but Gitlab has no Bind that gives access to that type of resource. With your `ClusterRole` you just gave it access to `secrets`, but nothing more.

Consider giving the ClusterRole more permissions, changing it to list all resources that you need to access:

```
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["secrets", "namespaces", "pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

For example this will give access to secrets, namespaces and Pods.

As an alternative, you can bind Gitlab's service account to `cluster-admin` to directly give it access to **everything**.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding gitlab-is-now-cluster-admin \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --serviceaccount=gitlab:default
```

Before doing so tho, consider the following:

> Fine-grained role bindings provide greater security, but require more
> effort to administrate. Broader grants can give unnecessary (and
> potentially escalating) API access to ServiceAccounts, but are easier
> to administrate.

So, it is way more secure to first decide which resources can be used by Gitlab and then create a Role / ClusterRole giving access to only those resources (and with the verbs that you need)

Comment: Thank you very much for the great explanation. I have updated the post, as now I can create the secret itself, but I'm still getting a similar error just for applying a file

Comment: @user3142695 I updated the answer with some more info. In general, you need to list and then bind all resources that you want to access. You can also use some roles or wildcards to give access to everything (or most things) but this of course has the cons of potentially escalating into problems (for example, if a container you don't trust needs to run in a namespace, you want to restrict what it can do). If you check the RBAC docs there are a lot of examples and explanations on what are the best practices!